# javaFX tableview can not correct render row

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

if I add more items into table until it generate a scroll bar. At this time, when I scrolled scroll bar, first name not equal "Jacob" was rendered yellow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzvnX.png)

```
table.setRowFactory(row -> new TableRow<Person>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null || empty) {

            } else {
                if (item.getFirstName().equals("Jacob")) {
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you scroll, the rows are reused to represent new items that are displayed. Your row factory *never* removes a style once it is set, so any rows that were yellow remain yellow no matter which items they are reused for.

In other words, once a particular row displays a person with first name "Jacob", that row will turn yellow, and then the style will never change (it will always stay yellow), even if the row is reused to display another person.

You need to reset the style if it the row should not be yellow:

```
table.setRowFactory(row -> new TableRow<Person>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Person item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null || empty) {
            setStyle("");
        } else {
            if (item.getFirstName().equals("Jacob")) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
            } else {
                setStyle("");
            }
        }
    }
});
```